# How to count words in a large file as soon as possible

Tags: python, counter

My file size is 16.5GB, and I count words by the follow code:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
with open('log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update(re.findall(r'\w+',line))
for w, t in c.most_common():
    print w, t
```

Is there any way to count it faster?

Comment: `wc log.txt` is all you need

Comment: May I suggest an improvement to @e4c5 which would be : `wc -w log.txt` It will output the number of words.

Comment: @e4c5 Except that your solutions does not do at all what the OP asks for (even if it is badly formulated). You just give the total number of words, whereas the OP program gives the count of individual words.